# Is It Safe to Delete My External HDD's Files/Folders That Are Hidden in Windows?

Tags: windows, external-hdd, delete, hidden-files

Is it safe to delete the Windows files and folders without having ANY repercussions? I do plan on using the external drive on Windows based computers here and there, but will use it on my Ubuntu based computer most of the time.

Here's a list of some of the files and folders that seem important: "pagefile.sys", "SYMEFA.DB", "found.000", "msdownld.tmp", "$RECYCLE.BIN", "System Volume Information", "IndexerVolumeGuid"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have recycled your old Windows HD ? Very commendable. I can see that there are no important files left: Pagefile.sys is the swap space for windows, found.000 is part or whole of a lost file, take a look at whats inside. SYMEFA.DB probably belongs to Symantec, could be virus defenitions. msdownload is a temp file for upgrades $RECYCLE.BIN is the Trash can, mounting the drive on another windows will create a new instance, see if its empty. System Volume Information is where windows keeps its backup files for restoring to a point in time, added to at updates, for roll back. Index.. is the Index for fast access, now useless. so you can delete them all. Hope you saved all your mails.
Happy Ubunting

Answer (score 1):

If you have not encountered any data missing on the drives, most probably it is safe to remove them. However this is something that you  will have to decide for yourself, based on understanding what these files are:

Here are some starting points:
pagefile.sys: http://lifehacker.com/5426041/understanding-the-windows-pagefile-and-why-you-shouldnt-disable-it
Found000: https://superuser.com/questions/124690/what-can-i-do-with-chk-files-in-found-000-folders
"System Volume Information"
https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows8_1-hardware/how-do-i-prevent-system-volume-information-files/815b0046-d631-4419-a43e-44083a3733f5
http://www.theeldergeek.com/system_volume_information_folder1.htm

Answer (score 1):

You may delete those files, `System Volume Information` and `$RECYCLE.BIN` will be recreated when you attach your drive to windows computer, `pagefile.sys` is related to Windows os so it isn't created on non system partitions and drives, `found.000` is related to Windows scan disk (check disk) utility, `msdownld.tmp` is related to installation of MS applications in Windows (like Internet explorer).